# How do I run non spock tests>?

Tags: grails, spock

In my grails test I have a bunch of integration tests that are standard grail integration tests and sock tests.

I can run all integration by doing

```
   grails integration:
```

I can run the spock integration tests only by doing

```
   grails integration:spock
```

How do I run all integration tests that are not spock tests?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grails test-app integration:integration` used for all JUnit Integration Tests.